# Return concatenated params in clojure

Tags: clojure

Need function or macro, which takes const parameter(*route*) and dynamic parameters (*args*) and return concatenated string of parameters:

```
user>(defn full-url [route & args] *need code* )
#'user/full-url
user> (def p1 "value1")
#'user/p1
user> (def p2 "value2")
#'user/p2
user> (def p3 "value3")
#'user/p3
user> (full-url "/init" p1 p2 p3)
"/init?p1=value1&p2=value2&p3value4"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also if this is meant to be used in a real web app you need to take care of URL encoding: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#URL_encoding.

Comment: @PiotrekBzdyl to logging restful services with parameters

Comment: You didn't answer the first question :)  Also I wouldn't do that. Use a map instead.

Comment: @m0skit0 i already tried define macro, something like Josh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a macro to do what you want:

```
(defmacro full-url
  [route & args]
  `(let [var-names# (map #(str %1 "=") '~args)
         var-vals# (list ~@args)
         joined# (clojure.string/join "&" (map str var-names# var-vals#))]
     (str ~route "?" joined#)))
```

Now, I would add that I do not think this is the best approach as it ties the names of your vars to the param names. IMO a better approach is to use a regular function that takes a map as a second argument, that has keywords and values.  Such as:

```
(defn full-url-fn
  [route params]
  (->> params
       (map #(str (name (first %)) "=" (second %)))
       (clojure.string/join "&")
       (str route "?")))

(full-url-fn "/init" {:p1 "value1" :p2 "value2"})
```

But, either way should work.

Comment: It is indeed a **very bad** idea.

Comment: @m0skit0 why? any arguments?

Comment: @Josh macro is not bad idea in my case, because variable names and query params are same. I have rest server and in a start point i want to log every parameter.

(defroutes myroutes
...
  (GET "/card" [id]
       (log/debug (full-url "/card" id))
       (get-card id))
...
)

Comment: @ykembayev Instead of explicitly getting the `id` parameter here, you should consider performing your logging at the start of your handler function, where you have the full query params in a map already, which would work perfectly with the function (not macro) above.